# UIButtonに設定した画像のcontentModeが効かない

Tags: ios, swift

UIButtonに設定した画像のcontentModeを設定したいのですが、有効になってくれません。
UIButtonのサイズは180/44、画像のサイズは44/44ですが、めいっぱいに表示されてしまいます。
これをボタンのサイズはイキで、画像の表示サイズだけ44にする方法はあるのでしょうか？

```
let btn:UIButton = UIButton()
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 44)
btn.setBackgroundImage( UIImage(named: "image.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
btn.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
self.view.addSubview( btn )
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIButton`の`imageView`は、`setBackgroundImage()`ではなく、`setImage()`で設定された画像を指しますので、以下のように指定する必要があります。

```
let btn = UIButton()
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 44)
btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "image.png"), forState: .Normal)
btn.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
self.view.addSubview(btn)
```

Comment: 早々にありがとうございます。意図通りできました！